# it's possible put a variable then deal with ids in kivy and python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

This is a simple code just to understand.
Imagine in kivy file I have three labels with different id like below code:

```
Label:
   id: L1
   text:"ex1"
Label:
   id: L2
   text:"ex2"
Label:
   id: L3
   text:"ex3"
Button:
   text:"ok"
   on_relase:
      root.btn_ok()
```

I want when click on Button "ok" [ call btn_ok function ] the text of label update to " Label update "

Python file

```
class a (App):
   steps=0
   def btn_ok(self):
      y=self.steps + 1
      update="L"+str(y)
      self.ids.update.text=" Label updated "
```

problem is that how I can put **variable** after .ids ex[ self.ids.**variable** ] it is possible ?
what is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. You only need to use the `ids[update]` format instead of `ids.update`. Something like this:

```
   def btn_ok(self):
      self.steps += 1
      update="L"+str(self.steps)
      self.root.ids[update].text=" Label updated "
```

Comment: Cool, Thank you for your reply,